# Unable to create Dimension Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, feature-class, dimensions

I am trying to create a Dimension feature class within a new geodatabase.

I right-click on the geodatabase and select the New, then Feature Class.

The New Feature Class window comes up and I can put in the Name, but when I use the drop down to select Dimension Features, I only get Polygon, Line, Point, Multipoint, Multipatch, and Annotation Features.

I am using ArcMap 10.2 standard license. As I understand, I should be able to do this.

How do I make a new Dimension Feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I thought the 2 computers had the same version. But I realized after I posted this that the computer only had the Basic license, and thus did not have the Dimension features available.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are following the Help for [Creating a dimension feature class with the default style](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/with_the_default_style/001r00000004000000/), it sounds like it is this step that is causing confusion:

> 4. Click the **Type** drop-down arrow and click **Dimension Features**.

I followed those instructions using a file geodatabase with one polygon feature class, and ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop Standard, and reached the point illustrated in the graphic without a problem.

[image]

If you are not using a file geodatabase, I recommend that you try doing it on one of those first to see the procedure work, and then re-try the same steps on whichever type of geodatabase you are using to see if your symptoms are isolated to that format.

As an afterthought I suspect that ***you may not have any feature classes in your new geodatabase***, and you will need at least one feature class present before you can dimension it.